# How to display text between nested Parenthesis using sed or awk or grep?

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a file inside that one line contains nested parenthesis, i want to display those words only.

Example:

```
(abc (defg) or hij(klmn)) and (opq(rstuv))
```

Expected Result:

```
defg
klmn
rstuv
```

I have tried with awk - `awk -F "[(())]" '{ for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) print $i}'`

I have tried with sed  -  `sed 's/.*(\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 1):

Using perl global matching and lazy quantifiers:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -n

use feature 'say';

while (/\((.*?\)[^(]*?)\)/g) {
    $m=$1;
    while ($m =~ /\((.*?)\)/g) {
       say $1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
defg
klmn
rstuv
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with `grep`?

```
$ echo "(abc (defg) or hij(klmn)) and (opq(rstuv))" | grep -o "([a-z]*)"
(defg)
(klmn)
(rstuv)
```

It catches the groups of `(` + `letters` + `)`.

I tried to get rid of the paranthesis but could not. This is my approach:

```
grep -Po '(?<=()[a-z]*(?=))'
```

but it indicates that *"grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length"*, as I guess it cannot decide up to which `)` to look for.

Comment: `echo "(abc (defg) or hij(klmn)) and (opq(rstuv))" | grep -Po '(?<=\()[a-z]*(?=\))'`

Comment: and we don't know what's in (), maybe not only letters. Replace `[a-z]`to `[^(|)]`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\(([^()]*)\)/\n\1\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//;/[^()]/P;D' file
```